How many named variations are in the Encyclopedia of Chess Openings?
I know there are 5 categories and 100 codes in each category, and each one of those (except for A00) have a move sequence and name. But there are other variations that don't have their own specific category and code. How many variations in total are there in ECO?
Here's an example of what I am talking about. All the following are listed under ECO code COO; each is a single variation: https://chessopenings.com/eco/C00/
So, regardless of code, how many variations are listed in ECO?

https://github.com/lichess-org/chess-openings has about 3500 variations, although there are many lines named the same thing. I don't know how many actually appear in the published ECO.
https://github.com/hayatbiralem/eco.json suggests 12 thousand named opening variations including SCID codes. If you are inclined, you can probably gather quick statistics with jq.

I am a contributor to eco.json, and created most the entries (nice to know it's noticed!).  I was curious as to how many variations are named in ECO proper.

Probably not what you are after, but consider that after 2 moves each there are almost 200 000 positions (https://www.chessprogramming.org/index.php?title=Perft_Results&oldid=26924 )

This doesn't answer the question
